# ActiveRecord query to filter nested has_many associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, postgresql, activerecord

I want to take an ActiveRecord model and filter the associations all the way up to the top level so that nested associations conforming to a certain condition prevent their parents from being inside the returned records.

Let me explain this better. I have the following models:

```rb
class SuperCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :categories
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  belongs_to :super_category
  has_many :sub_categories
  has_many :books
end

class SubCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :books
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sub_category
  belongs_to :category
  attr_accessible :show_me #boolean
end
```

In the SuperCategoriesController, I have:

```rb
class SuperCategoriesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @super_categories = SuperCategory.all #here is where I want to query
    respond_with(@super_categories)
  end
end
```

Hitting the `/super_categories.json` endpoint, I'll get something that looks like this which is the whole tree in JSON format since my .jbuilder partial adds all of the nested associations:

```
[
  { 
    name: "supercategory1",
    categories: [
      { 
        name: "category1",
        books: [
          { show_me: true },
          { show_me: true },
          { show_me: false }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "category2",
        sub_categories: [ 
          { 
            name: "subcategory1",
            books:[
              { show_me: false }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "supercategory2",
    categories: [
      {
        name: "category3",
        books: [
          { show_me: false }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

What I'd like to do in the controller if I pass it a param such that `show_me = true`, then I'd like to not show any of the Books, SubCategories, Categories and SuperCategories which have books with `show_me == false`.  Here is what I've tried:

```rb
class SuperCategoriesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if params[:show_me] == true
      @super_categories = SuperCategory.joins(:categories).joins(:sub_categories).where(:books => { show_me: true })
    end
    respond_with(@super_categories)
  end
end
```

This produces an error because I don't know how to join `:categories` to `:sub_categories` to `:books`.  What I'd like the result to be:

```
[
  { 
    name: "supercategory1",
    categories: [
      { 
        name: "category1",
        books: [
          { show_me: true },
          { show_me: true }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Basically, when I call `@super_category.categories` there should only be those categories which have nested books where `show_me == true`. Similarly, if there are SubCategories with books where `show_me == true`, it should return those too. Is there an ActiveRecord combination of `.joins` and `.where` that gets me there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work :

```
SuperCategory.joins(categories: :books).where("books.show_me = ?", true)
   &
SuperCategory.joins(categories: :sub_categories, :books).where("books.show_me = ?", true)
```

Comment: & is just seperating 2 alternates in the answer no need to add it to code